# Writing Excel Worksheets from C#

Tags: c#, excel

This code is only manipulating data if I create excel spreadsheet/file Worksheet using C#. If I provide it already created excel file for writing or manipulation, it throws an exception:

"The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1'(Worksheet in excel file which is referred in **Data Source**).
Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."

This is code I am trying:

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=D:\Temp\table1.xlsx;" + @"Extended Properties= 'Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;'

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con);
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;


cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [table1] (id INT, name VARCHAR, datecol DATE );";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1](id,name,datecol) VALUES(1,'AAAA','2014-01-01');";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1](id,name,datecol) VALUES(2, 'BBBB','2014-01-03');";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table1](id,name,datecol) VALUES(3, 'CCCC','2014-01-03');";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Book1 SET Name = 'Current Tag' WHERE id = 3;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you have to use Access database commands to edit your Excel file?
Otherwise you could have a look at the

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

assembly, which provides direct access to Excel files:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Obviously there are many ways to achieve a purpose, I am trying it this way. In this way excel file is treated as a database, And these are not specifically ACCESS DB commands SQL SERVER uses the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, since I'm not into DB commands I can't help you with that approach. I hope you can figure it out somehow, though!